# R using diff: non-numeric argument to binary operator error

Tags: r, types

We parse a CSV-File with some numbers with the following command:

```
tt <- read.table("test2.csv",sep=";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And it works. Printing`tt[1,]` yields a nice vector and `sd(tt[1,])` is sensible.

However, when we try

```
diff(tt[1,])
```

The command-line returns the error:

```
Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] :
    non-numeric argument to binary operator error
```

Why is that? Any ideas?

Comment: The error: `non-numeric argument to binary operator error` happens when you try to perform any arithmetic operation beween an R numeric type and an R NON-numeric type.  For example: `0.5 + list(10,20,30)[1]` produces the error.  Wheras `0.5 + as.numeric(list(10,20,30)[1])` avoids it by ensuring both sides are numeric, and prints `10.5`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I presume that in your `tt[1,]`, that

```
class(tt[1,])
# [1] "data.frame"
```

So if you use `as.numeric`, you should be okay.  Try this:

```
diff(as.numeric(tt[1,]))
```

---

Here's an example that we can inspect:

```
tt <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2)
is.vector(tt[1,])
# [1] FALSE
class(tt[1,])
# [1] "data.frame"
diff(tt[1,])
# Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
#   non-numeric argument to binary operator
as.numeric(tt[1,])
# [1] 1 2
diff(as.numeric(tt[1,]))
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
for (i1 in 1:length(dat.diff))
{
diffy <- diff(as.numeric(dat.diff[,i1]))
dat.diff[,i1] <- c(diffy, NA)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this issue is related to the class dataframe (df). The issue is that you are trying to run diff() on a possibly multi column df. Based on the documentation, the argument for diff required is a vector or matrix. I would suggest trying this:

```
TS_tt <- ts(tt$col, start= (the date you would like to start the time series)
```

then run:

```
adjusted_tt <- diff(tt, difference= 1)
```

Hope this helps.