# How do I operate basic functions within a column in R?

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I apologize for the poor phrasing of this question, I am still a beginner in R and I am still getting used to the proper terminology. I have provided sample data below:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 7, 19, 45), y=c(10, 12, 15, 19, 24))
View(mydata)
```

My intention is to find the x speed, and for this I would need to find the difference between 1 and 2, 2 and 7, 7 and 19, and so on. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `diff` function.

```
> diffs <- as.data.frame(diff(as.matrix(mydata)))
> diffs
   x y
1  1 2
2  5 3
3 12 4
4 26 5
> mean(diffs$x)
[1] 11
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! Is there any way I could specify the function to only find the differences in the x values?

Comment: You can simply do `diff(mydata$x)`.

Comment: Does this work with data frames? When I run this it gives me the error message "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: @PaulIbrahim: [non-numeric argument to binary operator error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478303/r-using-diff-non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator-error)

Comment: @d125q thank you, this worked! However, when I run it, in the new table it provides there is no name for the column. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr::lead()` and `dplyr::lag()` depending on how you want the calculations to line up

```
library(dplyr)

mydata <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 7, 19, 45), y=c(10, 12, 15, 19, 24))
View(mydata)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(x_speed_diff_lead = lead(x) - x
         , x_speed_diff_lag = x - lag(x))

#    x  y x_speed_diff_lead x_speed_diff_lag
# 1  1 10                 1               NA
# 2  2 12                 5                1
# 3  7 15                12                5
# 4 19 19                26               12
# 5 45 24                NA               26
```

Comment: So if my "x" variable was really named "player_x", where would I substitute it? Would it just be {mydata %>% 
  mutate(x_speed_diff_lead = lead(player_x) - player_x
         , x_speed_diff_lag = player_x - lag(player_x))}, because when I run that i get the following error message : {Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator}

Comment: You also have to change the name in your data: `mydata <- data.frame(player_x = c(1, 2, 7, 19, 45), y=c(10, 12, 15, 19, 24))`. Then you can run `mydata %>% mutate(x_speed_diff_lead = lead(player_x) - player_x, x_speed_diff_lag = player_x - lag(player_x))`

Comment: Rather than a vector, what if the values I am trying to use for subtraction are data frames? Would I just enter the name of the data frame in place of the vectors?

Comment: @PaulIbrahim - Are you asking how to do this for each variable in a data frame? If so, then you can use `do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(mydata, function(x) { lead(x) - x }))`. I can add this to my post if you would like. If this isn't what you are asking, then let's continue this in chat.